# How To resolve Role based authentication using Keycloak using Spring Webflux In ApiGateway

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, authorization, keycloak

I have decoded Jwt token like that. I added User Realm Role Token Mapper in Client Scope using Keyclock server. Thus we can access that claim directly from jwt.

```
{
  "exp": 1707597391,
  "iat": 1707597091,
  "jti": "505e8da0-1035-49fc-be74-1c59ab15ac03",
  "iss": "http://localhost:8181/realms/spring-boot-microservices-realm",
  "aud": "account",
  "sub": "bcb69d29-b6a4-4c74-96f5-4e89e3f741a1",
  "typ": "Bearer",
  "azp": "spring-cloud-client",
  "session_state": "f36ff533-9403-4b15-9099-d1679e4afd13",
  "acr": "1",
  "allowed-origins": [
    "/*"
  ],
  "realm_access": {
    "roles": [
      "offline_access",
      "ADMIN",
      "uma_authorization",
      "default-roles-spring-boot-microservices-realm"
    ]
  },
  "resource_access": {
    "account": {
      "roles": [
        "manage-account",
        "manage-account-links",
        "view-profile"
      ]
    }
  },
  "scope": "email profile",
  "sid": "f36ff533-9403-4b15-9099-d1679e4afd13",
  "email_verified": false,
  "roles": [
    "offline_access",
    "ADMIN",
    "uma_authorization",
    "default-roles-spring-boot-microservices-realm"
  ],
  "preferred_username": "admin"
}
```

Thats here my Security Config file

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebFluxSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {


    @Bean
    public SecurityWebFilterChain securityFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http) throws Exception{
        http
        .authorizeExchange(exchange -> exchange
                .pathMatchers("/api/product/**").permitAll()
                .pathMatchers("/api/user/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
                .anyExchange().authenticated())
                .oauth2ResourceServer((oauth2) -> oauth2
                .jwt(Customizer.withDefaults()));

        return http.build();
    }



    @Bean
    public JwtAuthenticationConverter con(){
        JwtAuthenticationConverter c = new JwtAuthenticationConverter();
        JwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter cv = new JwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter();
        cv.setAuthorityPrefix(""); // Default "SCOPE_"
        cv.setAuthoritiesClaimName("roles"); //Default "scope" or "scp"
        c.setJwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter(cv);
        return c;
    }


}
```

I can obtain roles on my Jwt token and i use JwtAuthenticationConverter however still i can not access role based path it throws me 403 Forbidden exception. I didn't understands what is the problem exactly.

Comment: please enable your spring security DEBUG logs and edit your question to include them. Also you can try setting `cv.setAuthorityPrefix("")` to prefix with the name `ROLE_` as in `cv.setAuthorityPrefix("ROLE_")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Preamble

You have 3 claims containing roles in your sample token, with the following [JSON path](https://jsonpath.com/) (in the solutions below, I expose how to extract all):

- `$.roles`
- `$.realm_access.roles`
- `$.resource_access.account.roles`

In your conf, you are using `hasRole("ADMIN")` (which expects a `ROLE_ADMIN` authority), but without adding a prefix to a Keycloak role which is `ADMIN`. This won't work. Two options:

- change `hasRole("ADMIN")` to `hasAuthority("ADMIN")`
- keep `hasRole("ADMIN")` but add a `ROLE_` prefix to Keycloak roles

`JwtAuthenticationConverter` is for servlet applications. It won't work in a `SecurityWebFilterChain`. Instead, configure a `ReactiveJwtAuthenticationConverter` as `http.oauth2ResourceServer((oauth2) -> oauth2.jwt(jwt -> jwt.jwtAuthenticationConverter(reactiveJwtAuthenticationConverter)))`

### Simplest Solution

In addition to `spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server` (which you should already have), add a dependency to [this Spring Boot starter](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/spring-addons-starter-oidc#spring-addons-starter-oidc) I maintain:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.c4-soft.springaddons</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-addons-starter-oidc</artifactId>
    <version>7.5.3</version>
</dependency>
```

Instead of `spring.security.oauth2.resourceserver.jwt.*`:

```yaml
issuer: http://localhost:8181/realms/spring-boot-microservices-realm

com:
  c4-soft:
    springaddons:
      oidc:
        ops:
        - iss: ${issuer}
          authorities:
          - path: $.roles
            prefix: ROLE_
          - path: $.realm_access.roles
            prefix: ROLE_
          - path: $.resource_access.*.roles
            prefix: ROLE_
        resourceserver:
          permit-all:
          - /api/product/**
```

```java
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    ResourceServerAuthorizeExchangeSpecPostProcessor accessControl() {
        return spec -> {
            return spec.pathMatchers("/api/user/**").hasRole("ADMIN");
        };
    }
}
```

### With just `spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server`

Change your security configuration to the following:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebFluxSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    SecurityWebFilterChain securityFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http, Converter<Jwt, Mono<AbstractAuthenticationToken>> authenticationConverter) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeExchange(exchange -> exchange
            .pathMatchers("/api/product/**").permitAll()
            .pathMatchers("/api/user/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
            .anyExchange().authenticated())
            .oauth2ResourceServer((oauth2) -> oauth2.jwt(jwt -> jwt.jwtAuthenticationConverter(authenticationConverter)));

        http.securityContextRepository(NoOpServerSecurityContextRepository.getInstance());
        http.csrf(csrf -> csrf.disable());
        
        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    ReactiveJwtAuthenticationConverter jwtAuthenticationConverter(Converter<Jwt, Flux<GrantedAuthority>> authoritiesConverter) {
        final var jwtAuthenticationConverter = new ReactiveJwtAuthenticationConverter();
        jwtAuthenticationConverter.setJwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter(authoritiesConverter);
        return jwtAuthenticationConverter;
    }
    
    static interface ReactiveAuthoritiesConverter extends Converter<Jwt, Flux<GrantedAuthority>> {}
    
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Bean
    ReactiveAuthoritiesConverter authoritiesConverter() {
        return jwt -> {
            final List<String> allRoles = new ArrayList<>();
            final var realmAccess = (Map<String, Object>) jwt.getClaims().getOrDefault("realm_access", Map.of());
            allRoles.addAll((List<String>) realmAccess.getOrDefault("roles", List.of()));
            
            final var resourceAccess = (Map<String, Object>) jwt.getClaims().getOrDefault("resource_access", Map.of());
            for(final var clientId : resourceAccess.keySet()) {
                final var clientAccess = (Map<String, Object>) resourceAccess.getOrDefault(clientId, Map.of());
                allRoles.addAll((List<String>) clientAccess.getOrDefault("roles", List.of()));
            }
            
            allRoles.addAll((List<String>) jwt.getClaims().getOrDefault("roles", List.of()));
            
            return Flux.fromStream(allRoles.stream().map(r -> "ROLE_%s".formatted(r)).map(SimpleGrantedAuthority::new));
        };
    }
}
```

### P.S.

The configuration is almost the same on a servlet resource server when using "my" starter, but you have to change quite a few interfaces when using only `spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server`.

Also, if the number of resource servers behind the gateway increases, you'll have to duplicate quite some configuration code (duplicated code always is a problem on the long term).

Apparently, your are configuring on the gateway the access control to downstream resource servers. For many reasons, I would not do that and set it on each resource server instead:

- it is unsafe to have services without security (even if these services are not exposed publicly)
- keep low coupling between services and the ability to define access control rules involving the accessed resource: things like `hasRole('ADMIN') or #user.id == authentication.name` which is impossible if you don't know the implementation of a `User` resource
- possibility to unit-test access control (see [this Baeldung article](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-oauth-testing-access-control) I wrote)

If your frontend is a single-page or mobile application, have a look at the [OAuth2 BFF pattern](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples/tutorials/bff) and consider configuring the gateway as an OAuth2 client with `oauth2Login()` (and the `TokenRelay` filter when routing a request to a resource server). Otherwise, the gateway would probably be better without security at all.

Comment: I am thankful to you my brother. I was just begining of the learning Spring boot application with using microservices architecture.